# iOS Distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, app-store, app-store-connect

I am having a problem with Xcode and the iOS Distribution certificate.
When I try to validate an archive, I get the message that there already is a valid distribution certificate but that it is not installed. My signing identity is also installed altho the message says it is not. I have no idea how this is possible since I have published apps to the app store before without any problems.

[image]

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Xcode version 6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing this:

- Create a NEW production certificate through developer.apple.com which
  requires you to use Keychain Access to create a new private key on
  your computer
- In the same developer portal, open your distribution Provisioning
  Profile used with this app and select the new production certificate
  which you just created. Generate the provision then download it and
  run it
- Run your app, Archive it, then export the archive.

  And viola

This took me days if not weeks to figure out, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the distribution certificate was installed in another mac.

You can:

- Export it from that mac and import to your Xcode.
- Go to apple developer website, revoke current distribution certificate. Then open Xcode get new distribution certificate for your mac.

Comment: The problem is that the certificate is not installed on another mac, as I only have 1 mac to work on.

Comment: So let try the second: "Go to apple developer website, revoke current distribution certificate. Then open Xcode get new distribution certificate for your mac."